# Github: I have to make a new SSH key after every use

Tags: github, intellij-idea, ssh, ssh-keys

I have a school and a personal Github, so I made an SSH key for my personal account and linked it up. It always works only once, then gives me

```
Push Failed
Git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey). Could not read from remote repository. Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists.
```

It works fine again after I delete the old SSH and make a new one, but this is obviously a huge hassle. I am on Windows 10, using Git Bash, and IDE is IntelliJ.

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Do I get it right that the first push works, and you can see the code on GitHub, but then it starts failing? Does it happen in the IDE only, or in GitBash as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this problem in the following way：

1.Create a file named `config` in the path `$USER_HOME/.ssh/`, then add following content.

```
# For school account
Host school_github
  HostName github.com
  PreferredAuthentications publickey
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa_school

# For personal account
Host personal_github
  HostName github.com
  PreferredAuthentications publickey
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa_personal
```

2.Run following command using git bash:

Change your school github repository configuration

```
git remote rm origin 
git remote add origin git@school_github:your_github_username/your_repo_name.git
```

You can hava a try.

Comment: Thanks, this worked out. I had created my config file, but was still using the original github "Host".

Comment: @RileyFitzpatrick you're welcome. As mentioned by Karthikeyan Vaithilingam , you can use the same SSH keys here.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to create SSH keys for each git service just upload the same public key to both personal and school accounts and it will work.

SSH public key is tied to you local account you have generate SSH keys only if you are using different local(machine) account or different machine

Comment: Really? That would make things much more convenient. If you only need one SSH, whats the point of the config file as per Michael's answer?

Comment: @RileyFitzpatrick the public key is like your name it identify you. You don't use one name in school and another one in home.

Comment: Also if you do a new clone you have to do the step 2 of Michael's answer. If you use same public key you don't need per repository configuration. This is how ssh public key authentication is done in most of the CI environment.

Comment: Okay, I'll do that then.Thanks!

Comment: github gives the error "Key is already in use" when I try to add it to both a personal and a 'school' account.

Answer (score 1):

Seems to me like when you try to authenticate, you are probably not using your keys.

If you run the command

```
ssh-add -l
```

You (should) see a list of all your keys. Each time you start a new session, make sure to start up the agent and add your keys.

```
eval `ssh-agent`
ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

Comment: I have added my keys, yes.

Comment: Indeed this causes the ssh agent to run with the credentials specified in id_rsa and it solves the error. What I don't understand is why I have to run this command every time that I log in again (which means once per day for me)? Can anybody clarify this?